# How to read a group of records from database by using aCursor?

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by, android-cursor

I have a `sqlite` database table. I need to get records from this table which are grouped by a `date` column. here's the query I am running:

```
select id as _id,sum(price) as price,sum(quantity) as quantity,sum(quantity*purchase_price) as cost,date from sales where date between '2018-08-24' and '2018-09-01' group by date order by date desc
```

this should return something like:

```
date            price        quantity        cost

2018-08-24      345          13              250
2018-08-26      425          15              450
```

this is a sample data that is returned from the query grouped by the date.  This is basically a sales report which tells that on `2018-08-24` you got `$345`, sold `13` items and spend `$250`.

I am receiving the result from the query using cursor, so I got a cursor object containing all this data. My question is that how can I access all this information from the cursor?

I tried accessing it using the regular way like this:

```
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantity"));
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price"));
cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cost"));
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
```

but this will just return the first row from the grouped records. just the first!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a loop over your cursor results. You can create a list for your results and get the cursor value into that list. maybe this can help you:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

    do{

       //Get_sales_values_from_Cursor

       cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantity"));
       cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price"));
       cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("cost"));
       cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));

       //move_to_next_row
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
```

you can even define a list and add your cursor values to that, So you can have all your statistics in a list.

Best regards.